# Detect color of UIView Area

Tags: ios, colors, area

I'm developing an App where user can draw on the screen. I started from **GLPaint** provided by Apple.

I want to detect if user has colored a specific area of the screen and I want to detect it each **1/15 of second** (or something like that, so very fast).

I thought to create a bitmap graphics context and pass it to `CGBitmapContextCreate` and than
draw my view into that context and loop through all pixels.

I'm looking for something more efficient...
Any help?

## UPDATE

I tried to use glReadPixels() but it is extremely slow... Maybe I miss something...
I tried to read a 100x100 area, but this method took like 1 sec to complete.
this is my code

```
- (void)isGameFinished
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float w = 100;
    float h = 100;
    GLubyte* pixelColors = malloc(w * h * sizeof(GLubyte) * 3);
    glReadPixels(x,y, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixelColors[0]);
    
    for(int i=0;i<w*h;i+=3)
    {
        ccColor3B color=ccc3(pixelColors[i],pixelColors[i+1],pixelColors[i+2]);
        NSLog(@"index: %d  r:%c g:%c b:%c",i,color.r,color.g,color.b);
    }
    
    free(pixelColors);
}
```

Comment: If you are using NSLog, then of course it will be slow because NSLog is slow.

Answer (score 1):

For calling a method every 1/15 of a second, you can use a [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) with a `frameInterval` of 4 (60 FPS / 4 = 15 times per second).  If you are using GLPaint, that means you are using OpenGL.  You can use the function [glReadPixels()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glReadPixels.html) to get the pixel data of a certain area.  However, you need to make sure that you have access to the underlying buffer in the function that gets called by CADisplayLink.  I'm not good enough at OpenGL to say how to ensure that.